# how to delete an object with an object key from a map object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

how to delete an object with an object key from a map object?

for example if i created a map object called `members`

```
const members = new Map();
```

here's the normal way for adding a new object inside `members`

```
//members.set(key, value);
members.set('Evelyn',{name: 'Evelyn', age: 25});
//here's how can we delete this object 
members.delete('Evelyn');
```

but when i started reading about map objects in es6 i was confused that the keys can be an object too!!

> Map is an object that lets you store key-value pairs where both **the keys and the values can be objects**

if so how can i delete the one with the object key ?

```
//key as an object
members.set({id: 1}, {
 name: 'Evelyn',
 age: 30
});
```

Comment: I guess you need to keep a reference. `const myKey = { id: 1 };`. Now use `myKey` as first param to set and delete.

Comment: i did that, but it returns false

Comment: why not take the `id` as key? do you have a special reason, why it should be an object?

Comment: What do you mean, "returns false"? And it works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vwd0tjqo/

Comment: @NinaScholz yes I know that I can do so, i just want to understand the concept

Comment: @ChrisG yes, it works. i dont know why it didnt work with me before i posting this question .. i tried it twice :D .. maybe because i tried it in the chrome console, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let objectKey = {id: 1};
members.set(objectKey, {
 name: 'Evelyn',
 age: 30
});

members.delete(objectKey);
```

As of my knowledge Maps compare via reference so this would be the only way.

Comment: i tried this way many times before posting this question and it returned false in chrome console .. that's why i came here.. but it works now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need eiter the same object reference of the key or seach with some infomation of the object.

```js
var members = new Map,
    id = 1,
    key;

members.set({ id: 1 }, { name: 'Evelyn', age: 30 });
console.log([...members]); // one element

for (key of members.keys()) if (key.id === id) members.delete(key);

console.log([...members]); // []
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```